Prove or counter-example: there exists g,h so that f can be bounded by gh
I am looking for a proof or counter-example to the statement

Let $X,Y$ be sets. For every $f:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ there exists functions $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)\leq g(x)h(y)$ for every $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

Can you help me?
Considerations
Using logarithms, the bound can be rewritten as $\log(f(x,y))\leq \log(g(x))+log(h(y))$, so the statement can be rewritten as

Let $X,Y$ be sets. For every positive $f:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ there exists functions $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\log(f(x,y))\leq g(x)+h(y)$ for every $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

The function $f$ does not need to have a finite supremum. So, functions like $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\; (x,y)\mapsto xy$ are included in the question. This particular $f$ has $g(x)=|x|$ and $h(y)=|y|$.
Functions of the form $z:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R},\; (x,y)\mapsto g(x)h(y)$ are used in the method of separation of variables.

There's a now-deleted answer suggesting $f(x, y)=x^y$ on the naturals is a counterexample, but that's not correct: $f(x, y) \leqslant x^x y^y$ since either $x \leqslant y$ in which case $x^y \leqslant y^y \leqslant x^xy^y$ or $y < x$ in which case $x^y < x^x \leq x^x y^y$.

A strategy I have been thinking about for a counter-example is constructing f based on a function that explodes from which we have removed the infinities/undefined points. For example, tan(z) is undefined for $z=\pi/2+k\pi$ and $1/z$ for $z=0$. Taking $f(x,y) = 0$ if $xy=\pi/2+k\pi$ else $tan(xy)$ or $f(x,y)= 0$ if $x=y$ else $1/(x-y)^2$ gives functions satisfying the conditions for the theorem, but which are non-trivial to find suitable $g(x)$ and $h(y)$ for. So far, I have not been able to show a counter-example with these functions.

A counter-example exists. Let $X=Y=[0,1]$ and
$$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
{0} & \text{if $x=y$,} \\
\frac1{|x-y|} & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
We'll prove that this is a counter-example.
Assume to the contrary that $g(x)$ and $h(y)$ as described in the problem statement exist.
We can assume without loss of generality that $\forall x \in X: g(x) > 0$ and $\forall y \in Y: h(y) > 0 $. To see this, replace negative values with their absolute value, which doesn't change the absolute value of $g(x)h(y)$ but makes sure it is positive and thus also an upper bound for $f(x,y)$.
$g(x_0) = 0$ for any $x_0$ is impossible as this implies $\forall y \in Y: g(x_0)h(y)=0$, but every $f(x_0,y)$ is positive except for $y=x_0$. The same argment can be made for $h(y_0) = 0$ being impossible.
The general idea of the proof is to look at any value $t \in [0,1]$ and set $x=t$ fixed for the moment and consider $y$ near $t$. $h(y)$ must be large there because it has to 'make up' for the finite and constant value $g(t)$ but $g(t)h(y)$ must be large because we are near the pole of $f(t,y)=\frac1{|t-y|}$. $h(y)$ being large everywhere then leads to a contradiction.
For the actual proof, start with choosing any positive real number $M$.
For a given value $t \in [0,1]$ $g(t)$ is a constant, but we know that in a neighbourhood of $y=t$, but exluding $y=t$ itself, the value $f(t,y)$ is unbounded, the nearer $y$ gets to $t$ the larger $f(t,y)$ will be. That means we can find a (possibly very small) open interval $I_t = (y_{t1}, y_{t2})$ around $y=t$ such that
$$\forall y\in (y_{t1}, y_{t2})\backslash\{t\}: h(y) > M.$$
For that we simply need that $f(t,y) = \frac1{|t-y|}$ will only have values above $Mg(t)$ in a small neighbourhood of $y=t$ and thus
$$g(t)h(y) \ge f(t,y) > Mg(t)$$
holds, from which $h(y) > M$ follows for all $y$ in $(y_{t1}, y_{t2})$ except for possibly $y=t$, because at $x=y=t$  we only have $g(t)h(t) \ge 0$ as condition.
It should also be noted that the openness of the interval is to be considered in $Y$ with the usual induced topology. So at $t=1$ the interval will necessarily end at and including $y_{t2}=1$, which is not an open interval in the real line but is in $Y$.
To summarize, we have for each $t \in X$ an open (in Y) interval $I_t$ including $t$, for which $$\forall y \in I_t\backslash\{t\}: h(y) > M$$ holds.
All those open (in Y) intervals now form an open cover of $Y$ (because each $I_t$ contains $t$ and $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.) Since $Y$ is compact (bounded and closed in $\mathbb R$), that means there is a finite subset of the those $I_t$ intervals that already cover $Y$. In each such $I_t$, by construction, at most for one value ($t$) we do not have $h(y) > M$. That means that we now know that $h(y) > M$ is true for all $y \in Y$ except for finitely many values (the indices $t$ of the finite subcover).
Now remember that $M$ was freely chosen from the positive real numbers. If we make a series of such choices, like $\forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots\}: M_i=i$ and define $S_i = \{y \in Y: h(y) \le M_i$}, then we proved above that each $S_i$ is finite.
That means that $S = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i$, as a countable union of finite sets is at most countable. OTOH, we have that $S=Y$, because each $y \in Y$ has a finite function value $h(y)$, and that must be smaller than some $M_i$ (which are unbounded).
Since Y has the cardinality of the real numbers (uncountable), this is a contradiction.

this should be in Counterexamples in Analysis

This works for $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ continuous, and analysis is too long ago to figure out for which other sets it works.
Take $g(z)=h(z)=\max(1,\max_{|x|+|y|\leq 2|z|}|f(x,y)|)$. If $|y|\geq |x|$ we get $g(x)h(y)\geq 1\cdot h(y)\geq |f(x,y)|$, and if $|x|\geq |y|$ we get $g(x)h(y)\geq g(x)\cdot 1\geq |f(x,y)|$.

This can be extended from continuous to "bounded on bounded sets" (if $X,Y \subset \mathbb R$). So 'simple' discotinueities don't matter.
